# Webdriver : Failed to install 'Webdriver' : version that satisfies the requirement webdrive

Tags: selenium, pycharm, webdriver

After updating Pycharm on Macos I get this error when I try to install `webdriver package :`

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement webdriver (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for webdriver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run this and its fixed :

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: Not working still have :
`Cannot find reference 'webdriver' in 'imported module com.decathlonWEB21.POMProject.Tests.Cart.selenium' `